# jQuery's ajax() did not call .fail() on net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call:

```
console.info('starting AJAX call');
$.ajax({
    url: '[myUrl]',
}).done(function (result) {
    console.info('success');
}).fail(function (e) {
    console.error('error');
});
```

This has been working great for many AJAX calls. If the call succeeds, I get a 'success' message in the console. If not, then it's a 'error' message.

However, today I noticed one strange case. The Chrome console looked like this:

```
starting AJAX call
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT          [myUrl]
```

So the AJAX call failed because of some timeout, but neither `success` nor `error` were logged in the console. This means that neither `done()` nor `fail()` were called by jQuery.

Unfortunately, it happened only once. I can't reproduce this. Most likely it was caused by a temporary network outage.

Is there a known case when this could happen? Shouldn't one of the callbacks `done()` or `fail()` ALWAYS be called?

Comment: since it happened only once, it might be that cached code was executed

Comment: But if cached code was executed, shouldn't there be a callback to `done()` or `fail()`?

Comment: i meant, if done and fail were not present in the cached code at all and that code was executed

Comment: Oh, I see. I think that's very unlikely. The same query has been executed hundreds of times, and both done() and fail() have been called many times by jQuery.